# Adding and removing an EventListener from an event

Tags: backbone.js, addeventlistener, easeljs

I'm not sure why it properly adds the event listeners when I render the view, but if I try to add one inside of another events function it's undefined and throws errors. How can I get it to properly add the event?

The workaround is to add a variable that stores whether the mouse is down, but I feel just adding and removing the event listener looks clears. It also negates the need for another variable of clutter.

Code:

```
render: function() {
        //sets up a new Easeljs stage called context
        Canvas.context.addEventListener("stagemousedown", this.handleMouseDown);
        Canvas.context.addEventListener("stagemouseup", this.handleMouseUp);
    },

    handleMouseDown: function() {
        console.log('down');
        Canvas.context.addEventListener("stagemousemove", this.handleMouseMove);
    },

    handleMouseMove: function() {
        console.log('moving');
    },

    handleMouseUp: function() {
        console.log('up');
        Canvas.context.removeEventListener("stagemousemove", this.handleMouseMove);
    }
```

Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleEvent' of undefined (09:32:29:386 | error, javascript)
at b.dispatchEvent (public_html/js/libs/easeljs-0.6.1.min.js:14:447)
at b._handlePointerMove (public_html/js/libs/easeljs-0.6.1.min.js:88:490)
at b._handleMouseMove (public_html/js/libs/easeljs-0.6.1.min.js:88:69)
at c.mousemove.f (public_html/js/libs/easeljs-0.6.1.min.js:87:34)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do a `_.bindAll(this)` in your `initialize` like so:

```
initialize: function () {_.bindAll(this);}
```

You should probably also move your event binding code to initialize because that will only get called once per instance whereas `render` may be called repeatedly, resulting in duplicate event handler bindings.

Comment: Thanks for that, seems to have solved my problem. I did move the event binding to the initialize function to keep the render function clean and quick.